# Quaternion Integration with Angular Acceleration

Tags: integration, matrix-calculus, quaternions, geometric-algebras

I'm looking to integrate angular velocity and acceleration into a quaternion.  After researching it, I came across [this site](https://www.ashwinnarayan.com/post/how-to-integrate-quaternions/), which shows that integrating angular velocity alone gives the following:
$$
q_{t} = exp(\frac{1}{2}\omega t)q_{0}
$$
where $\omega$ is the vector of angular velocities.  Numerical integration does give an answer close to this as well.

Finding a reference for how to do this with angular acceleration was a bit more difficult, but I was able to find [this paper](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10097724) which gives the following
$$
q_{t} = exp(\frac{1}{2}\omega t +\frac{1}{2}\dot{\omega}t^{2})q_{0}
$$
where $\dot{\omega}$ is the vector of angular accelerations.  I thought this was interesting, since given the resemblance to the kinematic equations, I would have thought the answer would have been this
$$
q_{t} = exp(\frac{1}{2}\omega t +\frac{1}{4}\dot{\omega}t^{2})q_{0}
$$

And indeed, numerical integration gives an answer closer to the latter.  For the tests I was using the difference was minor, so it could also just be that I made a mistake in the code I wrote for the numerical integration.

Can anyone confirm which of these is correct, or if it's a completely different answer.
Appreciate it.

Comment: The general formula is $\dot q = \frac12\omega q$. Your first equation is the case $\dot\omega = 0$ and your second/third equations are the case $\ddot\omega = 0$. Your second link references this work: A. Muller, “Approximation of finite rigid body motions from velocity
fields". After having a glance it seems that your third equation is correct, but this fact is nontrivial; it involves analyzing the [derivative of $\exp$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map). You will see from Muller that higher-order approximations do not follow the trivial pattern you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's compare some series expansions, Taylor and exponential. The DE is
$$
\dot q(t)=\frac12\omega(t) q(t).
$$
Its derivative is
$$
\ddot q = \frac12\dot\omega q+\frac12 \omega\dot q=\left(\frac12 \dot\omega+\frac14\omega^2\right)q
$$
This gives a quadratic Taylor polynomial of
$$
q(t+\Delta t)=\left(1+\frac12\omega(t)\Delta t+\frac12\left(\frac12 \dot\omega(t)+\frac14\omega(t)^2\right)\Delta t^2\right)q(t)+O(\Delta t^3)
$$
One the other hand we get the exponential
$$
\exp(a\Delta t+b\Delta t^2)=1+(a\Delta t+b\Delta t^2)+\frac12(a\Delta t+b\Delta t^2)^2+O(\Delta t^3)
$$
So yes, it has to be $a=\frac12\omega(t)$ and $b=\frac14\dot\omega(t)$, the non-commutativity of the quaternions does not play a role up to this point.

You would have to look into the sources cited in the cited paper to see if there are non-trivial reasons for the cited formula or if this is a simple typo, as this formula was not further used in the exposed theory.